# How can I display products that are booked in the future?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

So I have 3 models - *booking, marquee, businessuser*. Booking belongs to marquee, marquee belongs to businessuser and businessuser has many marquees.

I am trying to create a find/where clause in my application helper that will only return marquees that are > current date and are belong to a booking (i.e booking has their id).

What I am currently able to display is bookings that have marquees. But I want it to display marquees that are booked.

This is the method I have in the application helper

```
 def upcomingbookings
   @bookings = Booking.all
   @futuremarquees = Booking.where("marquee_id")
 end
```

booking has the field :startdatetime compared against Date.today

Just to clarify the business logic : Marquee is a tent that people can book for their party. So there a lot of marquees in the system. When someone makes a booking it stores the marquee_id. Booking has its own variables such as startdatetime and eventtype. I am creating a page that when a businessuser signs in they can view all the marquees they added to the system that currently have a booking

Comment: what field on marquee has the date you want to compare against?

Comment: @upcomingmarquees = Marquee.where("startdatetime > ? AND   businessuser_id = ? ", Date.today, session[:businessuser_id] ) . I know that is incorrect but they are the fields being used anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# returns Marquee records having at least one booking in the future
marquees = Marquee.includes(:booking).where('bookings.startdatetime > ?', Date.today)
```

If you want to find `Marquee` of the future belonging to a specific `Booking`:

```
marquees = Marquee.includes(:booking).where('bookings.startdatetime > ?', Date.today)
marquees = marquees.where(booking: { id: params[:booking_id] })
```

Comment: This seems close to what I need. However I got this error association named 'booking' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: @FergusMorton did you defined `has_one :booking` in the `Marquee` model to reflect the `belongs_to :marquee` of the `Booking` model?

Comment: Wow, I had not...Thank you very much for your help. It is working perfectly now. You have saved me many hours Yoshi

Comment: You're welcome :) don't forget to select the answer that solved your problem. Have fun with Rails!

Comment: Yoshi, just one last question. Marquees can be booked for several different dates (same marquee can be booked in june then in july etc). If Marquee1 is booked 3 times, it should show up 3 times when I look at future bookings. How would I do that?

Comment: Ah, simply replace the `includes` with a `joins` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
@futuremarquees = Booking.where(startdatetime: Date.today..Float::INFINITY, marquee_id: x)
```

Comment: This is just displaying bookings though. I am looking to display marquees that are booked, and whose booking start date is greater than Date.today

Comment: Something like this maybe? `Marquee.where.not('booking_id' => nil).joins(:booking).having('booking.startdatetime > ?', DateTime.now)`

Comment: Yeah this seems to be on the right track, however I received this error.wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: What version of Rails? In Rails 3 you may have to do something like `Marquee.where('booking_id IS NOT NULL').joins(:booking).having('booking.startdatetime > ?', DateTime.now)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a date field called startdatetime, try:

`@futuremarquees = Booking.where(['startdatetime > ?', DateTime.now])`

Comment: This is returning all bookings that were created after the current datetime. Where as I want to return all marquees that are booked whose booking has a startdatetime greater than date.today.

Comment: This can't really happen : `created_at` is filled when we create the record in the DB, therefore `created_at` will never be greater than the current DateTime

Comment: sure, it should be `startdatetime` instead

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do something like this

```
def upcomingbookings
 @futuremarquees = Marquee.where(['startdatetime > ?', DateTime.now] )
 # then you can do futuremarquees.marquee
end
```

Comment: But @futuremarquees is just returning all marquees created after current date right? I want to display marquees that are booked, and the booking start date is greater than Date.today.

Comment: @futuremarquees should return all the marquees that are superpose to start on the future assuming that startdatetime is in the right place

Comment: I see where the confusion is. Startdatetime is a variable of model Booking, not marquee

Comment: a marquees is a movie? and the Booking is like a ticket for the movie and you want to get all the tickets sold that are going to be redeem in the future

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Marquee is a tent that people can book for their party. So there a lot of marquees in the system. When someone makes a booking it stores the marquee_id. Booking has its own variables such as startdatetime and eventtype. I am creating a page that when a businessuser signs in they can view all the marquees they added to the system that currently have a booking. I hope that clears up some confusion